# Android open another app and jump to specific Activity

Tags: android

I know we can use Intent to open an App.But what I want to ask is like that:
How can I directly jump to the specific Activity.I also know that we can use intent-filter.But if we don't know the scheme,host,Params Name,what can i do.
For example,how to jump to the Facebook and open our company's home page.
How to jump to the Line Group Directly.
Thanks.

Comment: you can jump to another application activity depending on the fields defined in another application

Comment: But how can i know other application's field